# Exuberant-ctags incorrectly tags python multi line class definitions

Tags: python, exuberant-ctags

Exuberant-ctags generate wrong tags when python class definition spans multiple lines, only the last line goes to the search pattern:

Consider the file `test.py`:

```py
class FirstSubclass(
    LongLineBaseClass, AnotherLongClassName,
    MoreBaseClassWithVeryLongName
):
    pass


class SecondSubclass(
    LongLineBaseClass, AnotherLongClassName,
    MoreBaseClassWithVeryLongName
):
    pass


class OneLineClass(LongLineBaseClass):
    pass
```

and the resulting `tags` file for `ctags test.py` (comments added):

```
FirstSubclass   test.py /^):$/;"    c !PROBLEM
OneLineClass    test.py /^class OneLineClass(LongLineBaseClass):$/;"    c !OK
SecondSubclass  test.py /^):$/;"    c !PROBLEM
```

Both `FirstSubclass` and `SecondSubclass` received the same search pattern (ex command): `/^):$` i.e. the only two characters of the last line of each class definition. This makes tags navigating in vim unusable.

Exuberant ctags version and info:

```
Exuberant Ctags 5.9~svn20110310, Copyright (C) 1996-2009 Darren Hiebert
  Compiled: Oct  7 2014, 13:52:37
  Addresses: <dhiebert@users.sourceforge.net>, http://ctags.sourceforge.net
  Optional compiled features: +wildcards, +regex
```

**What I've tried:** I used the ctags with and without `language-python` `kinds`, parameters and nothing.

---

Any ideas ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Universal-ctags (https://ctags.io), an unofficial fork of Exuebrante-ctags, can extract the patterns expectedly:

```
[yamato@slave]~% cat /tmp/foo.py 
cat /tmp/foo.py 
class FirstSubclass(
    LongLineBaseClass, AnotherLongClassName,
    MoreBaseClassWithVeryLongName
):
    pass


class SecondSubclass(
    LongLineBaseClass, AnotherLongClassName,
    MoreBaseClassWithVeryLongName
):
    pass


class OneLineClass(LongLineBaseClass):
    pass

[yamato@slave]~% u-ctags -o - /tmp/foo.py
u-ctags -o - /tmp/foo.py
FirstSubclass   /tmp/foo.py /^class FirstSubclass($/;"  c
OneLineClass    /tmp/foo.py /^class OneLineClass(LongLineBaseClass):$/;"    c
SecondSubclass  /tmp/foo.py /^class SecondSubclass($/;" c
```

Moreover it can fills inherits fields:

```
[yamato@slave]~% u-ctags --fields=+i -o - /tmp/foo.py
u-ctags --fields=+i -o - /tmp/foo.py
FirstSubclass   /tmp/foo.py /^class FirstSubclass($/;"  c   inherits:LongLineBaseClass, AnotherLongClassName, MoreBaseClassWithVeryLongName 
OneLineClass    /tmp/foo.py /^class OneLineClass(LongLineBaseClass):$/;"    c   inherits:LongLineBaseClass
SecondSubclass  /tmp/foo.py /^class SecondSubclass($/;" c   inherits:LongLineBaseClass, AnotherLongClassName, MoreBaseClassWithVeryLongName
```